# Layout should use overflow-y: scroll to prevent flickering

Tags: feature-request, design

It's  the first time I've noticed this on a SE site but I guess it applies not only to Apple.SE.

On pages where the contents load relatively slowly (e.g. sometimes,  [the "Users" page](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users)) there is a noticeable Flash of when the page is built, and at some point gets a vertical scroll bar. The page's contents move 16px to the left once the scroll bar is added.

It's a minor thing, but noticeable. I would consider using `overflow-y: auto` in order to force a scroll bar, whether there is need for one or not. It would make for a smoother browsing experience.

Bumping this, as it still happens.

Comment: Funnily enough, this *might* be a Windows-only problem - I can't for the life of me remember how OS X displays scroll bars. It should be fixed anyway IMO.

Comment: Does it happen in all your browser?

Comment: @Loïc No. I see the flicker only in Chrome 10. IE shows a disabled scroll bar by default; FF removes the scrollbar when it doesn't need it, but does that more smoothly.